# Query Bigquery datasets from multiple regions on Dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sqlx, dataform

Is there a way to query multiple tables that belong to datasets existing on different regions on Dataform.

I know that Dataform use `defaultLocation` to locate tables. But In my case, datasets won't be always on the same region.

Example :

**dataform.js**

```
defaultLocation : "europe-west1"
```

And then in `defintions` I will be querying datasets :

```
dataset1 -> location : "EU"
dataset2 -> location : "europe-west1"
```

Comment: Are you aiming to join tables in two regions? If so, then it is not possible without transferring data from one region to other. But if you just using tables in separate queries in different regions then its possible. let me know

Comment: @BihagKashikar It's not a join. I'm querying datasets from different regions in separate queries. How could I do that ?

Comment: Another question, in separate .sqlx files or one sqlx.? If its separate, have you tried with in separate sqlx files defining schema like this https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/table-settings#override-settings once you give the dataset id, this will also inherit its location. does this help?

Comment: The queries are in separate .sqlx files. 
In my case, my defaulfLocation is europe-west1. The dataset I'm calling is in region EU. And I call it via declarations.js.

I have tried many ways but I still get this error : 
 bigquery error: Not found: Dataset projectid:eu-dataset was not found in location europe-west1.

Comment: Hi there, can you try giving defaultLocation : "EU" in dataform.js. I did just this and when I wrote queries in to access tables in separate .sqlx files in different EU regions, the compiler did not give me error. However, I can't post the answer as I am getting permissions issue which I am not able to fix it. let me know if above change helped

Comment: If I do change defaultLocation to "EU" in dataform.js, my query will work for one time. But I want to schedule my queries in airflow, and this solution won't be useful, becuase other queries that are running in "europe-west1" won't be able to work then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252807/discussion-between-snowfire-and-bihag-kashikar).

Comment: Hi @Snowfire, Is your issue resolved? Have you tried creating separate repositories for different locations. For more information you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/develop-workflows-js).

Answer (score 1):

As per requirement, you can create separate repositories for different locations.

For more information you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/develop-workflows-js).

If this doesn't help, you can follow this issue in this [issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/275218829) that has been raised by @BihagKashikar.

However, there is no ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.